# "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token" when using app permissions to access my OneDrive

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have a web application that allows me to sign in to my OneDrive account using delegated permissions to authorize the app to browse my drive files on my behalf. I'm now trying to build a server-side job that needs to work with these files and therefore needs application permissions granted with admin consent.

I've followed various instructions to achieve this, but no matter what I do I keep getting this 403 error:

> Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token

The application I've registered in Azure portal has the application permission `Files.Read.All` and I've granted admin consent. I'm obtaining my access token as follows:

```cs
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("<client-id>")
    .WithClientSecret("<secret>")
    .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"))
var apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
string[] scopes = { $"{apiUrl}.default" };
result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

I'm then using the returned token to request `"{apiUrl}v1.0/drives/<my-drive-id>/items/<drive-item-id>"`

And this is where I get the access denied. Clearly the API expects my token to have either a `roles` claim or an `scp` claim.

After reading [this related post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57526395/either-scp-or-roles-claim-need-to-be-present-in-the-token-using-when-application) I did wonder if the problem is related to the fact I'm using the same app registration for the front end and back end operations (so it has a mix of delegated and application permissions) but I tried creating a new app registration with only the application permissions and it was the same error.

Also, that post suggests I should expect to see either and `scp` or a `roles` claim in my token (depending on choice of auth flow) but I get neither of these claims. That led me to [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456209/getting-the-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-api) which suggests I need to explicitly include `roles` in my access token, but `roles` isn't listed as an optional claim in the *Token configuration* blade of the app registration.

So I'm stuck. Can anyone help?

---

***UPDATE 1***

I've tried constructing the auth request manually now using a POST to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token` and a form body that includes `grant_type=client_credentials` and now I'm finding the `roles` claim is returned in the token. So I guess the `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` wasn't building a client credentials auth request as I had assumed. However, when I use this token to make the above Graph API request for a drive item I get the error:

> Tenant does not have a SPO license

When I've encountered this before I've been told to use `common` instead of my tenant ID. However, when I make that change in this case I'm again left with a token that doesn't have a roles claim.

Comment: (1) Does the logged on user has necessary permissions to access the above resource? Check the same using https://jwt.ms and validate the scp/permissions (2) Make sure you're testing the above scenario in Onedrive for Business or the resource which you have a valid license.

Comment: This is a personal OneDrive, and using application permissions not delegated, so the logged on user isn't relevant in this case

Answer (score 0):

The absence of the `roles` claim indicates that you app (or service) hasn't been granted any application permissions (i.e. app roles) for the API (in this case, Microsoft Graph), in the tenant where the token request is being made.

You need to ensure the the application permissions (app roles) you expect the app to use to make the API call have been granted in the tenant where you are making the API call.